# Toggle Chrome showing end-of-text (and other ascii) character

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, special-characters, ascii

I've seen some posts about general "weird" characters, but those don't exactly answer my question. In particular, I'm seeing the end-of-text character. In chrome it's rendering as:

[image: with etx character]

while in firefox the same page, same text renders as:

[image: without etx character]

As you can see there's that little superscript `L`-like character. If I copy that and paste it into Notepad++ for example, it tells me which character it is: in this case, `ETX`.

The `ETX` is there - I can copy/paste the text from Chrome or Firefox and the `ETX` faithfully shows in Notepad++.

My question is **not** why the `ETX` is there, but rather, is there a way for me to toggle the viewing of such characters within Chrome? Or Firefox for that matter?

<sub>I tried to paste the exact string here into the post, but SU strips the character (rightfully-so)</sub>

### Additional Info

As requested, here is a site that has this character and is showing:

https://reesespuffsgameday.prizelogic.com/

For me, I see it just before the first instance of the word "Sweepstakes"

Comment: Are you able to provide the URL where this occurs so we can see it/test it/experiment with it? There's a similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39603446/why-is-this-symbol-showing-up-on-chrome-and-not-firefox-or-edge

Comment: There's no URL - I'm working via localhost on a project -- but I did find a live site that has it, I'll update the question

Comment: In my Windows 8.1, Google Chrome Version 54.0.2840.99 m (64-bit)  does not render that `└` (_Box Drawings Light Down And Left_) but Notepad does (yes, I'm talking about Windows native `Notepad.exe`).  Another proof of the `ETX` character presence: select [`Win & Sweepstakes` text from this link](https://reesespuffsgameday.prizelogic.com/), copy&paste in an open `cmd` window as `echo "Win & ^CSweepstakes"` gives `"Win & ♥Sweepstakes"` Note that `♥` _Black Heart Suit_ (Alt+3) is `cmd` replacement for `ETX` (Alt+03).